# useImperativeHandle usage for children componenent but cannot get function from parent

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, parent-child, use-ref, react-forwardref

I have app writen by react:

the main App is:

```
function App({articles}) {
    ...
    const SortVote=()=>{
      console.log(childRef.current);
      console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(childRef.current))
      childRef.current.SortVote();
    }
  
    const [art, setArt]= useState(articles);
    const childRef = useRef();

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h8k-navbar header={title}></h8k-navbar>
            <div className="layout-row align-items-center justify-content-center my-20 navigation">
                <label className="form-hint mb-0 text-uppercase font-weight-light">Sort By</label>
                <button data-testid="most-upvoted-link" className="small" onClick={SortVote}>Most Upvoted</button>
            </div>
            <Articles articles={art} cRef={childRef}/>
        </div>
    );

}
```

the children componenet is:

```
function Articles({ articles, cRef }) {
  const [arts, setArts] = useState(articles);
  const sortVote = () => {
    const result = articles.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.upvotes > b.upvotes) {
        return -1;
      }
      if (a.upvotes < b.upvotes) {
        return 1;
      }
      return 0;
    });
    setArts(result);
  };
  const sortDate = () => {
    const result = articles.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.date > b.date) {
        return -1;
      }
      if (a.date < b.date) {
        return 1;
      }
      return 0;
    });
    setArts(result);
  };
  useImperativeHandle(cRef, () => ({
    sortVote,
    sortDate
  }));
  if (articles)
    return (
      <div className="card w-50 mx-auto">
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Upvotes</th>
              <th>Date</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {arts.map((item, index) => (
              <tr data-testid="article" key={index}>
                <td data-testid="article-title">{item.title}</td>
                <td data-testid="article-upvotes">{item.upvotes}</td>
                <td data-testid="article-date">{item.date}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
}
```

I use useImperativeHandle in children Component and Try to use 'childRef.current.SortVote()' in parent Component to invoken children Component function. But the browser has error:

```
childRef.current.SortVote is not a function
```

The full code is on: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vy7df9

At useImpertiveHandle hook, the SortVote and sortDate is already defined function, but why here still error SortVote is not function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Issue

The `useImperativeHandle` is used with passed React refs, *not props holding ref values*.

[useImperativeHandle](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle)

> `useImperativeHandle` customizes the instance value that is exposed to
> parent components when using `ref`. As always, imperative code using
> refs should be avoided in most cases. **`useImperativeHandle` should
> be used with `forwardRef`**:
>
> ```
> function FancyInput(props, ref) {
>   const inputRef = useRef();
>   useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
>     focus: () => {
>       inputRef.current.focus();
>     }
>   }));
>   return <input ref={inputRef} ... />;
> }
> FancyInput = forwardRef(FancyInput);
> ```

In your code you are not passing a ref to the child component, you are passing a prop that has a ref value.

```
<Articles cRef={childRef} articles={art} />
```

vs

```
<Articles ref={childRef} articles={art} />
```

## Solution

First, update the function signature of `Articles` component to consume a React ref. Note that this is a ***second*** argument passed to the function, `props` object being the first.

```
function Articles({ articles }, ref) {
  ...

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    sortVote,
    sortDate
  }));

  if (articles) {
    return (
      ...
    );
  }
  return null;
}
```

Next, wrap the `Articles` component in [React.forwardRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactforwardref).

```
Articles = forwardRef(Articles);
```

Finally, pass a ref to the `Articles` component. Note, it is `sortVote`, not `SortVote`.

```
function App({articles}) {
  const [art, setArt]= useState(articles);
  const childRef = useRef();

  ...
  const SortVote=()=>{
    console.log(childRef.current);
    console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(childRef.current))
    childRef.current.sortVote();
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      ...
      <Articles
        ref={childRef}
        articles={art}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

### Update

You've also a bug in the child `Articles` component. `Array.prototype.sort` does an in-place sorting, which means it mutates the `arts` state. You first need to copy the array before sorting it. `Array.prototype.slice` is a simple functional programming way to copy the array inline before sorting it.

```
function Articles({ articles }, ref) {
  const [arts, setArts] = useState(articles);

  const sortVote = () => {
    const result = articles.slice().sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.upvotes > b.upvotes) {
        return -1;
      }
      if (a.upvotes < b.upvotes) {
        return 1;
      }
      return 0;
    });
    setArts(result);
  };

  const sortDate = () => {
    const result = articles.slice().sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.date > b.date) {
        return -1;
      }
      if (a.date < b.date) {
        return 1;
      }
      return 0;
    });
    setArts(result);
  };

  ...
```